# Can't resolve jar library in InteliJ when adding to libraries in SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to add the Apache commons library to my Scala project. Before moving it to SBT it worked by just adding it to the library or global library setting within my InteliJ project. Now that I moved to sbt it doesn't resolve anymore and I'm getting errors.

How do I add a local jar library as an SBT dependency within InteliJ?

Comment: Have you tried placing it in the `lib` folder of your project? How do you import your sbt project to the IntelliJ? How does your build definition look like?

Comment: I simply created a new sbt project from intelij, I can't seem to find a lib folder though.

Comment: Just create one manually and drop the jar there

Comment: *"Now that I moved to sbt"* - would you mind explaining the project build in sbt? How did you import the project to IDEA? What about the versions of the software used? It's just today when the Scala plugin for IDEA was updated so you may need to upgrade it, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure SBT is able to find that dependency. Follow a standard way of adding unmanaged dependencies to your project as described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies). Citing that reference:

> Unmanaged dependencies
>
> Most people use managed dependencies instead of unmanaged. But
>   unmanaged can be simpler when starting out.
>
> Unmanaged dependencies work like this: **add jars to lib** and they will
>   be placed on the project classpath. Not much else to it!
>
> You can place test jars such as ScalaCheck, specs, and ScalaTest in
>   lib as well.
>
> **Dependencies in lib go on all the classpaths** (for compile, test, run,
>   and console). If you wanted to change the classpath for just one of
>   those, you would adjust dependencyClasspath in Compile or
>   dependencyClasspath in Runtime for example.
>
> **There’s nothing to add to build.sbt** to use unmanaged dependencies,
>   though you could change the unmanagedBase key if you’d like to use a
>   different directory rather than lib.
>
> To use custom_lib instead of lib:
>
> unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "custom_lib"
>
> baseDirectory is the project’s root directory, so here you’re changing
>   unmanagedBase depending on baseDirectory using the special value
>   method as explained in more kinds of setting.
>
> There’s also an unmanagedJars task which lists the jars from the
>   unmanagedBase directory. If you wanted to use multiple directories or
>   do something else complex, you might need to replace the whole
>   unmanagedJars task with one that does something else.

To test if it works well just run SBT externally (outside of IntelliJ from cmd) and execute `update` or `compile` tasks. If your library is used in the code and you get no errors then SBT is happy. Afterwards simply use "Import Project" in IntelliJ and select "Use auto-import" option in one of the wizard steps.

Comment: If you have jars correctly in lib folder updating SBT should be enough. You can achieve this also by doing some meaningless changes to build.sbt (save needed) and undoing them. At this point there should be top of code view notification "build.sbt has changed" -> click "refresh project". I think this is same as Scott is basicly doing.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your build.sbt:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.5"`